# Find details of missing records in ADF Pipeline

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am building a very basic ADF Pipeline with copy data activity loading data from salesforce to salesforce. After i debug the pipeline i get few records skipped in load. How can i find the detail of these skipped records.
I am new to ADF. Any inputs will be helpful.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked this doc? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-fault-tolerance
You can enable logging if you want to track the skipped columns [image]